# Maintain the desired amount of Kafka consumers implemented as threads in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, apache-kafka

I have a `Runnable` which is a Kafka consumer. I'm running N instances of this consumer in my application.

Currently, if there is an error (exception) in the consumer, it just logs the error and stops working. In this case I have N-1 consumers running.

Is there a way to auto-start a new instance of the consumer and run it, so I can have N consumers again?

The logic I want to achieve is the same of Supervisord, which tracks the processes and restarts them, if needed. Though, I would prefer to have some standard solution and not to write my own.

My `Runnable`s are managed like that now:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
executor.execute(consumerInstance1);
executor.execute(consumerInstance2);
```

Comment: I don't understand why you don't catch the exception and restart a consumer with the same group.id ?

Comment: You mean with `Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler`? This is what I mean by writing my own solution. I thought, this task is pretty often and there should be some kind of stadard supervisor library, but couldn't find it.